# Rails 4 app on Heroku getting Elasticsearch IndexMissingException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch

- Have a Rails 4 app, want to add full-text search using ElasticSearch.
- The app runs fine locally using foreman but when submitting a search
  query in the deployed version on heroku I get an error:
  "IndexMissingException" (see full error log below.)
- I believe the issue is related to that I am not correctly pointing to the ElasticSearch index on heroku. I have tried following the [heroku instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai#installing-the-add-on) but to be honest I don't fully understand the "Using your index section" and I think that is the source of the problem.

Any advice that can be provided on proper setup of a Rails 4 app with ElasticSearch on Heroku would be appreciated!

Here are some details that hopefully can help in debugging this.

**Ruby/Rails Versions**

```
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
Rails 4.2.1
```

**From Heroku Logs**

```
2015-04-12T20:52:36.506728+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=better" for 98.14.231.17 at 2015-04-12 20:52:36 +0000
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553113+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553116+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ([404] {"error":"IndexMissingException[[posts] missing]","status":404}):
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553118+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:   <% end %>
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553120+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: 
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553121+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <ul>
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553123+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
2015-04-12T20:52:36.550831+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (27.2ms)
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553124+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <li>
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553126+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:         <%=  post.content %>
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553129+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/posts/index.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb___4115668764297473519_69883416675900'
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553127+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     </li>
2015-04-12T20:52:36.553132+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-12T20:52:36.549950+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Search (18.6ms) {index: "posts", type: "post", q: "better"}
2015-04-12T20:52:36.516050+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"better"}
2015-04-12T20:52:36.515947+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2015-04-12T20:52:36.551104+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 18.6ms)
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.3'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem "figaro"
gem 'annotate', '~> 2.6.5', group: :development
gem 'pry-rails', group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'ffaker'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.0.0.pre', github: 'reactjs/react-rails'
gem 'thin'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails'
```

**Model**

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
end

Post.import
```

**Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      if params[:q].nil?
      @posts = []
    else
       @posts = Post.search(params[:q])
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
  <%= form_for posts_path, method: 'get' do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Search for" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
  <% end %>

  <ul>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li>
        <%=  post.content %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**Heroku Bonsai Add-On**

I followed the [instructions at Heroku for installing Bonsai](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai#installing-the-add-on)

**Created an Index**

```
curl -X POST http://[[MY BONSAI URL]]
```

and got:

```
{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
```

As I mentioned, I think the issue is tied to that I not properly using/pointing to the index.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with django. I think the solution is to update mapping manually using elasticsearch _mapping url after creating the index.

example:

```
PUT /search/_mapping/person 
{
"person": {
        "properties": {
            "person_id": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-put-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had not imported the records from my model on Heroku. This involves first ensuring that you are requiring elasticsearch rake tasks and then running the import task on Heroku with a FORCE=true parameter

1. See
   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails
2. Scroll down to Rake tasks and follow the instructions.
3. When
   importing the records on Heroku, be sure to include FORCE=true, eg

   $ heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Article' FORCE=true

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me, importing fixed the error.

```
bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:all
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:

```
Searchkick::ImportError - IndexMissingException[[..._users_development] missing]:
  searchkick (1.3.0) lib/searchkick.rb:111:in `perform_items'
  searchkick (1.3.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:82:in `perform_items'
  searchkick (1.3.0) lib/searchkick.rb:102:in `perform_bulk'
  searchkick (1.3.0) lib/searchkick.rb:95:in `queue_items'
  searchkick (1.3.0) lib/searchkick/index.rb:60:in `bulk_index'
```

In my case, elasticsearch was already installed and configured for an existing project but I had to do that the installation in my computer at work.

I will state all steps and you can skip a step if you have already done it. You can also follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails).

**Step 1: Download ElasticSearch**

I am using elasticsearch 2.3.1 so I downloaded it from here: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-2-3-1

**Step 2: Install the ElasticSearch Ruby Gem**

I have the following in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'searchkick'
```

Then run: `bundle install`.

**Step 3: Import data from your models into Elasticsearch**

Create this file: `lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake`, if you do not already have it. Then paste this line inside it:

```
require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'
```

Now, run the following command to import data from your models into ElasticSearch:

```
rake environment elasticsearch:import:all DIR=app/models
```

Once this is done, you should get a message like this:

```
[IMPORT] Loading models from: app/models
```

I hope this helps someone facing the same or similar issue. Happy coding :)